# Check CPU and Memory usage of pods in Kubernetes realtime (per-second-basis)

Tags: kubernetes, cpu-usage

I am trying to get CPU Usages from pods in every one or two second intervals. Currently what kubernetes supports is through metric server which it polls metrics in 15s intervals. It is too coarse grained for my case. What other options are available to get realtime CPU/Memory usages?

Comment: Prometheus is a popular open-source monitoring system that collects and stores metrics from various sources. One of the metrics that Prometheus scrapes from the kubelet is `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`, which represents the cumulative CPU time consumed by a container in seconds. For memory, `container_memory_working_set_bytes`, which represents the amount of memory that is being used by a container.